# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unsupported keyword: GREATER_THAN_EQUAL (1): [IsGreaterThanEqual, GreaterThanEqual]

Tags: spring-data-jpa, azure-cosmosdb

I'm using Spring JPA on Azure cosmos DB.

My code is here

```
public interface DeviceTelemetryRepository extends DocumentDbRepository<DeviceTelemetry, String>{

    List<DeviceTelemetry> findAll();

    @Query(value="SELECT * FROM DeviceTelemetry where deviceId= ?1 and date >= ?2 and date <= ?3", nativeQuery = true)
    List<DeviceTelemetry> findDeviceTelemetryByDeviceIdAndDateGreaterThanEqualAndDateLessThanEqual(@Param("deviceId") int deviceId,
                                                               @Param("from") long from,
                                                               @Param("to") long to    );

}
```

Error Messages:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unsupported keyword:
>   GREATER_THAN_EQUAL (1): [IsGreaterThanEqual, GreaterThanEqual]    at
>   com.microsoft.azure.spring.data.documentdb.repository.query.DocumentDbQueryCreator.from(DocumentDbQueryCreator.java:82)
>   ~[spring-data-cosmosdb-2.0.3.jar:na]  at
>   com.microsoft.azure.spring.data.documentdb.repository.query.DocumentDbQueryCreator.and(DocumentDbQueryCreator.java:56)
>   ~[spring-data-cosmosdb-2.0.3.jar:na]  at
>   com.microsoft.azure.spring.data.documentdb.repository.query.DocumentDbQueryCreator.and(DocumentDbQueryCreator.java:25)
>   ~[spring-data-cosmosdb-2.0.3.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.AbstractQueryCreator.createCriteria(AbstractQueryCreator.java:122)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:2.0.10.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.AbstractQueryCreator.createQuery(AbstractQueryCreator.java:95)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:2.0.10.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.AbstractQueryCreator.createQuery(AbstractQueryCreator.java:81)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:2.0.10.RELEASE]

Do you have any expriences? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for spring-data-cosmos db.
I got an answer from Microsoft Github.

https://github.com/Microsoft/spring-data-cosmosdb/issues/347

azure-documentdb-spring-boot-starter is the old version.